# Codewars abort: process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm testing my code for 'Find the unique number' and I'm encountering

> STDERR:
>
> Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete
>
> SIGKILL Process exited prematurely with a SIGKILL signal. Server
>   Execution Error:
>
> The server timed out waiting for the code to finish executing. It is
>   possible that this is due to high server load. It may also be caused
>   by inefficent code. Please try your request again.

This often occurs with my code. Is this related to the quality of code, or is it a server problem? I hope that it refers to my code.

```
find_uniq = lambda a: [x for x in a if a.count(x) == 1].pop()
# I have passed all of this tests
# btw I'm using python 3
test.assert_equals(find_uniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]), 2)
test.assert_equals(find_uniq([ 0, 0, 0.55, 0, 0 ]), 0.55) 
test.assert_equals(find_uniq([ 3, 10, 3, 3, 3 ]), 10)
Time: 92ms Passed: 3 Failed: 0
```

Comment: "It may also be caused by inefficent code." Run your code in a real environment. Does it take longer than 12 seconds to complete?

Comment: This looks like your code is being killed by the server for being too slow. You could try submitting your `find_uniq` function to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for help with increasing its speed.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would explain the long runtime. Even the 92ms seem to be rather long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very large sets, this is inefficient, as you check redundant set elements multiple times.  For instance in your first test set, you will check **1** five times.  Try this modification:

```
find_uniq = lambda a: [x for x in set(a) if a.count(x) == 1].pop()
```

If you want to save a few microseconds, just grab the first element instead of **pop**ping:

```
find_uniq = lambda a: [x for x in set(a) if a.count(x) == 1] [0]
```

Comment: Indeed, it was my mistakes. Thank you so much! 'set' had solved this problem.